# c# extract value from nextnode

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following xml part and am trying to extract the value where key is known. The example below is a snippet, from a larger xml that contains 1000's of  nodes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DictionarySerializer>  
    <item>
        <key>key1</key>
        <value>CONTENT1</value>
    </item>
    <item>
        <key>key2</key>
        <value>CONTENT2</value>
    </item>
</DictionarySerializer>
```

i assume the above is a string called xml,
then with

```
XDocument.Parse(xml)
.Descendants("key")
.Where(x => (string)x.Value == "key1")
.FirstOrDefault().NextNode.ToString()
```

I can get the string `<value>CONTENT1</value>` But i simply cannot get my head around how to get the value of the value node to to say.
I am afrad it is super simple, and i just are stuck in a coffein loop :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get all keys and values from the XML from all 1000 elemnts. You can use:

```
Dictionary<string, string> elements = new Dictionary<string, string>();

xml.Root.Elements().ToList().ForEach(xmlElement =>
{
    elements.Add(xmlElement.Descendants("key").First().Value,
                 xmlElement.Descendants("value").First().Value);
});
```

So, the elements dictionary will contain all of your 1000 nodes.

Comment: So that was a 1st for me at stackoverflow. Definetely not a last. Thanks for a bunch of good answers.

Comment: @KimIsaksen Good..Happy to help you..!!

Answer (score 1):

```
XDocument.Parse(xml)
.Descendants("key")
.Where(x => (string)x.Value == "key1")
.FirstOrDefault().Value.ToString()
```

you should use **.Value** property instead of **.NextNode**

Answer (score 1):

Try to cast *NextNode* to *XElement* and get *Value* from it.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you can use XPath expressions.

```
expression = @"//Item[Key='1']/Value"
XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDocument.SelectNodes(expression);
```

This would give you the value node(s) of items with Key=1. Just find the value of the desired node.

I believe using XDocument you can also try,

```
string output = xDocument.XPathEvaluate(expression);
```